# How to solve this differential equation $y-x\frac{d y}{d x}=\frac{d y}{d x}y^2e^y$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have to solve this equation $$y-x\dfrac{d y}{d x}=\dfrac{d y}{d x}y^2e^y.$$

This implies $$\dfrac{d x}{d y}-\frac{1}{y}x=e^yy.$$

But unfortunately, I am not able to use the method of solving by using the integrating factor.

Also, this is not an exact differential equation. I tried to make it exact and then solve but couldn't do it because of the factor $e^y$.

So, what should I do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P=-\frac1y,\,Q=ye^y$ works just fine, viz. $R=\frac1y,\,x=y\int e^ydy=ye^y+Cy$.

Comment: Oh sorry, I somehow read the question wrong. I thought it is $xe^y$ instead of $ye^y$. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Saikat But that would have been even easier, viz. $\frac{d\ln x}{dy}=e^y+\frac1y$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Homogeneous equation ${{dx}\over{dy}}={1\over y}x$

separate the variable it implies ${{dx}\over {dx}}={{dy}\over{dy}}$

Method of variations of constants: look of a solution of the form $x=A(y)y$, $x'=A'(y)y+A(y)$.

$x'-{1\over y}x=A'(y)y+A(y)-A(y)=e^yy$ Which implies $A'(y)=e^y$